# Google Docs Print Error : Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.info" from accessing a frame with origin "https://docs.google.com"

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, ssl, google-docs

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.info" from accessing a frame with origin "https://docs.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

My iframe src "HTTP://" But it keeps changing it to "HTTPS://" and it will not work! Getting the error message: Blocked a frame with origin "https://docs.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://...". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

**My Code show below :**

```
<iframe id="docfile" src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?php echo urlencode(UPLOAD_URL.FILE_NAME); ?>&embedded=true" width="800" height="470" style="border: none;"></iframe>

<button id="printbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Print</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
      window.frames["docfile"].focus();
      window.frames["docfile"].print();
}
</script>
```

Please help me.....